# Create a tibble with values from and to a year range based on a year column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

**The problem:**

I have would like to create a tibble that uses a combination of the `years` column to create a `from_to_years` column, with the addition of a `xend` and `yend` column. So that I can ultimately create a ggplot with geom_segment between the years.

**Reproducible example:**

```
set.seed(1)
tibble::tibble(site = c(rep("A",3), rep("B",3)),
               year = rep(2010:2012, 2), 
               x = rnorm(6),
               y = rnorm(6))
```

**produces...**

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  site   year      x      y
  <chr> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A      2010 -0.626  0.487
2 A      2011  0.184  0.738
3 A      2012 -0.836  0.576
4 B      2010  1.60  -0.305
5 B      2011  0.330  1.51 
6 B      2012 -0.820  0.390
```

**and I would like to create:**

```
# A tibble: 6 x 7
  site  year_from year_to xstart ystart   xend  yend
  <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 A          2010    2011 -0.626  0.487  0.184 0.738
2 A          2010    2012 -0.626  0.487 -0.836 0.576
3 A          2011    2012  0.184  0.738 -0.836 0.576
4 B          2010    2011  1.6    0.305  0.33  1.51 
5 B          2010    2011  1.6    0.305 -0.82  0.39 
6 B          2011    2012  0.33   1.51  -0.82  0.39
```

**Note:**

I would like every combination of years for each site.

Comment: @akrun you are correct, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing around with the answer by @Park I found a tidy approach using expand_grid() to create an empty tibble to then populate with the main data frame:

```
expand_grid(year_from = df$year |> unique(), 
            year_to = df$year |> unique(),
            site = df$site|> unique()) |> 
  filter(year_from < year_to) |> 
  left_join(df, by = c("year_from" = "year", "site")) |> 
  rename(xstart = x, 
         ystart = y) |> 
  left_join(df, by = c("year_to" = "year", "site")) |> 
  rename(xend = x, 
         yend = y)
```

```
# A tibble: 6 x 7
  year_from year_to site  xstart ystart   xend  yend
      <int>   <int> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1      2010    2011 A     -0.626  0.487  0.184 0.738
2      2010    2011 B      1.60  -0.305  0.330 1.51 
3      2010    2012 A     -0.626  0.487 -0.836 0.576
4      2010    2012 B      1.60  -0.305 -0.820 0.390
5      2011    2012 A      0.184  0.738 -0.836 0.576
6      2011    2012 B      0.330  1.51  -0.820 0.390
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method with `combn`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
tmp <- df1 %>%
     group_by(site) %>%
     summarise(year_col = combn(year, 2,  FUN = function(x)
      tibble(year_from =x[1], year_to = x[2]), simplify = FALSE),
         .groups = 'drop') %>%
     unnest_wider(c(year_col))
map(c("y", "x"), function(x)
   map2(c("year_from", "year_to"), c('start', 'end'), 
     ~ df1 %>%
         select(-all_of(x)) %>%
         left_join(tmp, ., by = setNames(c('site', 'year'), c('site', .x))) %>%
         setNames(., c('site', 'year_from', 'year_to', 
          str_c(last(names(.)), .y)))  ) %>% 
        reduce(inner_join)  ) %>% 
     reduce(inner_join)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 7
  site  year_from year_to xstart   xend ystart  yend
  <chr>     <int>   <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 A          2010    2011 -0.626  0.184  0.487 0.738
2 A          2010    2012 -0.626 -0.836  0.487 0.576
3 A          2011    2012  0.184 -0.836  0.738 0.576
4 B          2010    2011  1.60   0.330 -0.305 1.51 
5 B          2010    2012  1.60  -0.820 -0.305 0.390
6 B          2011    2012  0.330 -0.820  1.51  0.390
```

---

Or another option is to reshape to 'long' format and then convert back to 'wide'

```
df1 %>%
     pivot_longer(cols = x:y) %>%
     group_by(site, name) %>%
     summarise(across(c(year, value), ~ 
        {val <- .x
      combn(seq_along(val), 2, FUN = function(x)
       tibble(start = val[x[1]], end = val[x[2]]), simplify = FALSE)}),
         .groups = 'drop') %>% 
      unnest(c(year, value), 
       names_repair = ~c("site", "name", "year_start",
           "year_end", "start", "end")) %>%
      pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = c('start', "end"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 7
  site  year_start year_end start_x start_y  end_x end_y
  <chr>      <int>    <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 A           2010     2011  -0.626   0.487  0.184 0.738
2 A           2010     2012  -0.626   0.487 -0.836 0.576
3 A           2011     2012   0.184   0.738 -0.836 0.576
4 B           2010     2011   1.60   -0.305  0.330 1.51 
5 B           2010     2012   1.60   -0.305 -0.820 0.390
6 B           2011     2012   0.330   1.51  -0.820 0.390
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `expand`,

```
df2 <- df %>% mutate(year2 = year) %>% select(-year)


df %>%
  group_by(site) %>%
  mutate(year2 = year) %>%
  expand(year, year2) %>%
  filter(year < year2) %>%
  left_join(df,by = c("year", "site")) %>%
  mutate(xstart =x, ystart = y) %>% select(-x, -y) %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("site", "year2")) %>%
  mutate(xend = x, yend = y) %>% select(-x, -y)
```